# Same email is evaluated as a spam for one user, and regular for the other

Tags: spam, spamassassin, spam-filter

I have mail server, with installed spamassassin to filter spam messages.

Problem I faced is that at 02h first user received email that is treated as a spam (and is was a real spam, moved to spam folder, and that's ok).

But at 07h another user received that same email, but it is not treated as a spam.

Can you tell me why that happened and why second email wasn not treated as a spam?

Comment: Spamassassin usually adds a fair amount of information about what rules it hit on in the headers, and the points it got, I'm guessing it was a high BAYES score that made the first one end up in Spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the limited information you provided, NO.

But you have individual user preferences and possibly individual Bayes databases that are different?

You do know that SpamAssassin adds headers with the rules that were triggered and the resulting spam score e.g. compare a regular message:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on ...
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-2.0 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,FREEMAIL_FROM,
    HTML_MESSAGE,RP_MATCHES_RCVD autolearn=ham version=3.3.1
```

to the lengthy spam report for a spam message:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on 
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Level: **********************
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=23.0 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_99,FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2,
    MSGID_FROM_MTA_HEADER,RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET,RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT,
    RCVD_IN_PSBL,RCVD_IN_SORBS_WEB,RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO,RDNS_DYNAMIC,TVD_RCVD_IP,
    TVD_RCVD_IP4,URIBL_AB_SURBL,URIBL_DBL_SPAM,URIBL_JP_SURBL,URIBL_WS_SURBL
    autolearn=spam version=3.3.1
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  4.5 URIBL_AB_SURBL Contains an URL listed in the AB SURBL blocklist
    *      [URIs: behoop.ru]
    *  1.6 URIBL_WS_SURBL Contains an URL listed in the WS SURBL blocklist
    *      [URIs: behoop.ru]
    *  1.2 URIBL_JP_SURBL Contains an URL listed in the JP SURBL blocklist
    *      [URIs: behoop.ru]
    *  1.7 URIBL_DBL_SPAM Contains an URL listed in the DBL blocklist
    *      [URIs: behoop.ru]
    *  3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
    *      [score: 1.0000]
    *  0.0 TVD_RCVD_IP4 TVD_RCVD_IP4
    *  0.0 TVD_RCVD_IP TVD_RCVD_IP
    *  1.2 RCVD_NUMERIC_HELO Received: contains an IP address used for HELO
    *  2.7 RCVD_IN_PSBL RBL: Received via a relay in PSBL
    *      [46.185.20.237 listed in psbl.surriel.com]
    *  0.8 RCVD_IN_SORBS_WEB RBL: SORBS: sender is an abusable web server
    *      [46.185.20.237 listed in dnsbl.sorbs.net]
    *  1.3 RCVD_IN_BL_SPAMCOP_NET RBL: Received via a relay in bl.spamcop.net
    *      [Blocked - see <http://www.spamcop.net/bl.shtml?46.185.20.237>]
    *  1.4 RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT RBL: RCVD_IN_BRBL_LASTEXT
    *      [46.185.20.237 listed in bb.barracudacentral.org]
    *  1.0 RDNS_DYNAMIC Delivered to internal network by host with
    *      dynamic-looking rDNS
    *  0.0 MSGID_FROM_MTA_HEADER Message-Id was added by a relay
    *  2.0 FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2 FSL_HELO_BARE_IP_2
```